# Compile a directory tree of separate apps (one entry point each), using CommonJS modules and ES6 modules

Tags: build, couchdb, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I am writing a [Couch app](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/). The output of the build process must be a directory tree of self contained JS files, like so:

```
dist
├── _attachments
│   ├── logo.jpg
│   └── splash.jpg
├── lists
│   └── sitemap.js
├── shows
│   ├── article.js
│   ├── home.js
│   └── dashboard.js
├── views
│   ├── recent
│   │   └── map.js
│   ├── featured
│   │   └── map.js
│   └── stats
│       └── map.js
│       └── reduce.js
```

Each output JS file is a complete app, with all imported modules inlined. Each input file is a separate entry point, which will require / import modules from a top level `lib` directory (and `node_modules` or course). The resulting `dist` directory is then deployed to a Couch by [Erica](https://github.com/benoitc/erica) (alternatives suggestions are welcome).

So far, I have tried the following:

- Compile with Babel (ES7 yay!), using Broccoli. Produces ES5 modules with CommonJS require statements; a further build step would be necessary to inline the imported modules.
- Browserify and uglify from the command line. It looks like this was only designed to produce a single output file.
- In a makefile, uglify each input separately and send the output to a matching directory path under `dist`. A work in progress, but not an ideal solution.

So, I am about to go back to Makefiles. Which are beautiful in an exotic way, but I would really like to stick with a modern / JS based build process - something like Broccoli or Gulp (or whatever). Suggestions?

**update**

I see that Webpack can build multiple output files for multiple entry points. But can it preserve the input directory structure?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to inline require js modules to make them available in your scripts. Is that right? You can do it but you don't need to because couchdb supports require js. This means that you can  do `var my_lib=require("path-to-some-lib")` and it'll work with couchdb.

Comment: Ok, so then I just need to transform ES6 and CommonJS modules to RequireJS modules. Do you have a link to docs about CouchDB's module loading capabilities? I haven't been able to find anything except some custom scheme based on metadata in comments (kanso).

Comment: I found [this post](http://caolan.org/posts/commonjs_modules_in_couchdb/) pretty useful. But [here is the official documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CommonJS_Modules). Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makefiles it is. I doubt this would work on anything but a Linux dev machine. Don't do it like this if you are publishing something for other people to use.

What this does is build a standalone app from each design doc in the `src` tree. The show docs, which use React to render pages in an isomorphic style, weigh in at several megabytes.

In order for CouchDB to be able to execute one of these apps, the output JS must evaluate to a global function declaration that implements the relevant part of the CouchDB API. To do that, I build a standalone UMD module, which attaches its output to a `global` object, if one exists. One does not exist in CouchDB, so we prepend a declaration, and append an expression that evaluates to the function exported by our module:

```
echo 'global={};' > $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.js
$(BUILD_CMD) --standalone func $(SRC_DIR)/$*.js >> $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.js
echo 'global.func;' >> $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.js
```

Here's the whole file:

```sh
SRC_DIR=src
BUILD_DIR=build

SRC := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -type f -print)

JS := $(filter %.js, $(SRC:src/%=%))
STATIC := $(filter-out $(JS), $(SRC:src/%=%))

BUILD_CMD=browserify -t babelify -g [ uglifyify -c -m ]
BUILD_DEV_FLAGS=--watch

all: dist

# Deploy to local CouchDB using Erica
# TODO: browser reload
install: $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(JS)) copy
    cd $(BUILD_DIR) && erica push couchra -v

copy: $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(STATIC))

# Transpile JS from ./src to ./build
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.js: $(SRC_DIR)/%.js
    mkdir -p $(dir $(BUILD_DIR)/$*)
    echo 'global={};' > $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.js
    $(BUILD_CMD) --standalone func $(SRC_DIR)/$*.js >> $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.js
    echo 'global.func;' >> $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.js

# Copy static files from ./src to ./build
$(STATIC:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%): $(STATIC:%=$(SRC_DIR)/%) $(BUILD_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    cp $(@:$(BUILD_DIR)/%=$(SRC_DIR)/%) $@

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

clean:
    rm -Rf $(BUILD_DIR)

.PHONY: clean dist
```

It is likely that at some point, I will convert this to plain shell scripts and `npm run` them.

Areas for improvement:

- Exclude commonly used libs from the build, and use CouchDB's CommonJS functionality to include them. This should more than halve the size of the design documents, and allow Couch to avoid a bunch of disk reading when loading the design doc to handle a request.
- Move the rendering code out of the show functions, and into update filters. That way, the HTML views can be created once per update, instead of on every write. Each doc would contain a few rendered versions of itself in a `renderedViews` member. Show and list functions would return or concatenate and return this static markup, which would eliminate the React app's execution time from the response time of server side rendered pages.